# Replacing vertical picture windows

Tags: windows, replacement

My rancher has several large single pane picture windows oriented vertically along the south and east sides of our house. All have storm windows that do a great job insulating from noise but the whole assembly could use a good spring cleaning. They are all rather old and the interior painted wooden frame around the windows has some blistering and cracking.
[image: east side window with casement]

The windows on the east side are "normal" in dimensions and topped with standard casement windows for ventilation. 
[image: east side window with casement]

On the south side are a cluster of tall, thin windows that reach all the way to the gabled ceiling. I believe that they are ~2 feet wide and between 8-10 feet tall - the tops are angled to the roof.

[image: south side windows with angled top]

I can't seem to find anything anywhere about fixing the framing or getting replacements for these oddly sized windows.

Would sectioning them in two so the top of each is a relatively small angled window and the bottoms are all the same size (say 2X8 ft) be a sound idea?

Would a double pane replacement be worth it, or would sticking with the custom storm windows (and/or replacing their old aluminum frame) be a better idea?

Comment: There are a lot of window manufacturers that do custom replacement windows, but I'm guessing the real answer hinges on how much sticker shock you're willing to endure.

Comment: @Comintern That's exactly what I was afraid of. If I can find at least a partial off-the-shelf solution (stacked 2'x4' windows?) to take the edge off of that, it would really help. Is there a way to do that? Does it look like I need to replace the whole sill?

Comment: Well, the south side will be the biggest hit with replacement windows, because they are appear to be low enough to require tempered glass (18" is the minimum around here). 24" is usually a standard width that gets stocked for replacements, but if you split them the bottom would likely still need to be custom. The sill really doesn't look like more than cosmetic damage from the picture. As long as the wood itself is sound and the windows aren't leaking, refinishing shouldn't be horribly difficult.